# <string> in header file

Tags: c++, string, header

I`m trying to define a variable of string type in a class definition in a header file. Is it possible?
Example:

```
/* Foo.h */   
#include <string>
class Foobar{
     int a;
     string foo;

}
```

Because somehow in main I can declare a string variable, but in the header it doesn’t recognize my string type.

Comment: I got two things from that: you never included any `std` and you missed a semicolon on your class.

Comment: it was just an example, that is why i forgot semi colon...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`string` lives in namespace `std`. Make that:

```
#include <string>

class Foobar {
    int a;
    std::string foo;
};
```

Comment: thanks, i forgot about std since i use usually using namespace std; :) i`m new with c++

Comment: Answered my question to which was unrelated to the original question. Thanks :-)